# apt-get database issue lubuntu 16.04 ....

Tags: apt

My apt-get database is all fouled up and I am getting this when running the top suggested fix:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
  libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice-common.
(Reading database ... 333538 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package     openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.2-9782
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

I've been unable to clear this with various suggestions (google discovered) in both command line and with synaptic.
Any ideas to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The packages `libreoffice-common` and `openoffice-debian-menus` both contain the file `/usr/bin/soffice` so only one of them can be installed at a time.

Currently you have `openoffice-debian-menus` installed, but as it isn't an official Ubuntu package I suggest to remove it using

```
sudo apt-get remove openoffice-debian-menus
```

Comment: I finally figured that out and removed the openoffice independently but thanks for the quick response. I've reinstalled the broken libreoffice stuff now and all is well. The reason I went to libreoffice in the first place was because openoffice was causing my system to reboot when it was invoked which is a little undesirable to say the least. I think I can go back to trying to fix my sound functionality which was what I was working on when all this blew up on me.